# Need a Help In Python for Returning Values

Tags: python

**Use the get_seconds function to work out the amount of seconds in 2 hours and 30 minutes, then add this number to the amount of seconds in 45 minutes and 15 seconds. Then print the result. ??**

***written the following code:***

```
def get_seconds(hours, minutes, seconds):
  return 3600*hours + 60*minutes + seconds

amount_a = get_seconds(2,30)
amount_b = get_seconds(45,15)
result = amount_a + amount_b
print("result:" + str(result))
```

after executing the code is showing following error
Error on line 4:
    amount_a = get_seconds(2,30)
TypeError: get_seconds() missing 1 required positional argument: 'seconds'

Can you please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function definition promises that the user will supply three numbers: hours, minutes, and seconds.  You didn't follow the rules: you left out the seconds.

```
amount_a = get_seconds( 2, 30, 0)
amount_b = get_seconds(45, 15, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise adding a default argument for seconds if you are not going to include a value for it every time you call the function. You can add a default argument in the function definition.

```
def get_seconds(hours, minutes, seconds = 0)
```

The arguments need to be added in the order of the parameters, except if you are using keyword arguments

Comment: Ah, yes -- thanks for the catch.  I've fixed my answer.  Yours is also good -- provided that OP is *allowed* to change the given function.  The wording of the assignment suggests to me that they cannot do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_seconds(hours, minutes, seconds):
  return 3600*hours + 60*minutes + seconds

amount_a = get_seconds(2,30,0)
amount_b = get_seconds(0,45,15)
result = amount_a + amount_b`
print (result)
```

Comment: In your answer, can you please explain how it works?